# Loop to build WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2005, loops, where-clause

I'm trying to figure out how to use a loop in a where clause. I have this code, where I want only the file names from the last 7 days. It works so far, I just wanted to make the code more dynamic/nicer :)

```
select a, b
from data1
where a in 
(
  'File_'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()-1)*10000+MONTH(GETDATE()-1)*100+DAY(GETDATE()-1) 
      AS VARCHAR)+'.TXT'
, 'File_'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()-2)*10000+MONTH(GETDATE()-2)*100+DAY(GETDATE()-2) 
      AS VARCHAR)+'.TXT'
, 'File_'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()-3)*10000+MONTH(GETDATE()-3)*100+DAY(GETDATE()-3) 
      AS VARCHAR)+'.TXT'
, 'File_'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()-4)*10000+MONTH(GETDATE()-4)*100+DAY(GETDATE()-4) 
      AS VARCHAR)+'.TXT'
, 'File_'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()-5)*10000+MONTH(GETDATE()-5)*100+DAY(GETDATE()-5) 
      AS VARCHAR)+'.TXT'
, 'File_'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()-6)*10000+MONTH(GETDATE()-6)*100+DAY(GETDATE()-6) 
      AS VARCHAR)+'.TXT'
, 'File_'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()-7)*10000+MONTH(GETDATE()-7)*100+DAY(GETDATE()-7) 
      AS VARCHAR)+'.TXT'
)
order by a
```

The file names are called File_YYYYMMDD.txt.

I searched other places and read a little about looping, but all I could figure out was something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < 7 BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

select a, b
from data1
where a in 
(
  'File_'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()-@i)*10000+MONTH(GETDATE()-@i)*100+DAY(GETDATE()-@i) 
     AS VARCHAR)+'.TXT'
)
order by a
```

Comment: [Please get out of the dangerous habit of casting/converting/declaring varchar/nvarchar/char/nchar without specifying the length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop thinking about looping. SQL Server isn't designed to loop, it's designed to work with sets. Take a look at the output of this:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (7) f = 'File_' 
    + CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (ORDER BY [object_id]), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), 112) + '.txt'
  FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT f FROM x;
```

Results:

```
f
-----------------
File_20130814.txt
File_20130813.txt
File_20130812.txt
File_20130811.txt
File_20130810.txt
File_20130809.txt
File_20130808.txt
```

Now, how can you use this set?

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (7) f = 'File_' 
    + CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (ORDER BY [object_id]), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), 112) + '.txt'
  FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT d.a, d.b FROM dbo.data1 AS d
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM x
  WHERE f = d.a
)
ORDER BY d.a;
```

Comment: Perfect that works really good. I didn't know the SQL Server isn't designed to loop, but now I know that this is the way to solve this problem. Is there a simple way to add another file to the code, I would like to add one more that has the same date format, but is named "File_Region_YYYYMMDD.TXT", but is used in the same way in the where clause.